# Prove that $\det A$ does not exceed $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A =(a_{ij}) ∈  M_n(\Bbb R)$ be a matrix with *nonnegative entries* such that the sum of the entries in each row does not exceed $1$. Prove that $|\det A|$ does not exceed $1$ too.

This is one of my exercise,I tried to induction,but i'm stuck. 
Help me please! Thanks

Comment: Where in the induction are you stuck? It seems like row expansion should give the induction step without much problem.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, After i using row expansion, how i can make sure that sum of these minor determinants does not exceed 1? Can you help me more cleary! Thanks!

Comment: Well that's not what you have to prove, since the determinant is not just the sum of the minor determinants; rather, each of those gets multiplied with one entry in the row you chose. See my answer for a one-line proof.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need induction. Prove/use the following two results: 1) the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, and 2) any eigenvalue of a nonnegative matrix has magnitude at most the largest row sum (just write out the eigenvalue equation to see why).

Comment: That's nice. Maybe it is worth to note that the infinity-norm is useful here (and that the eigenvalues might be complex).

Answer (score 3):

$\lvert \det(A) \rvert \stackrel{\text{row exp.}}= \lvert \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} \cdot a_{1j}\cdot \det(A_{1,j}) \rvert \le \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{1j} \rvert \cdot \lvert \det(A_{1,j}) \rvert \stackrel{\text{ind. hyp.}}\le \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{1j} \rvert \stackrel{\text{assumption}}\le 1$

Comment: That's what I had in mind.  The OP probably does not know the Perron Frobenius theorem, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a direct consequence of Hadamard's inequality (determinant is just a volume). Google it!

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt part (b) of this proof about stochastic matrics: https://yutsumura.com/eigenvalues-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-always-less-than-or-equal-to-1/

Copying most their proof here per site policy on self contained answers:

For eigenvector $\lambda$, $AV = \lambda V$ for some nonzero vector $V$, and looking at the $i'th$ row of that matrix equation gets:

$$\sum_{j} A_{i,j}V_{j} = \lambda V_{i}$$

Let $V_k$ be the element of that $V$ with the largest magnitude, that is

$$|V_k| = \max( |V_1|, |V_2| \dots)$$

Note $|V_k > 0|$ by the fact $V$ is an eigenvector as stated above.

Now use the triangle inequality $|\sum_k m_k n_k| \le \sum |m_k| |n_k|$ and the above facts to prove that $|\lambda| \cdot |V_k| = |\lambda \cdot V_k| \le |V_k|$.  Then the fact that the determinant is the product of the eigen values to finish your proof.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use expansion by minors in an inductive proof.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  How do you intend to prove that $a - b + c - d \dots < 1$ ?

Comment: @DanielV: What are $a,b,c, ...$?

Comment: I agree with @kimchilover this works. It's spelled out in my answer. +1.